# How does Karma know what file to run as server?

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, mocha.js

I want to run some HTTP tests against my server using the karma test runner with mocha framework. I am not sure how to specify I want `app.js` to be the file that the server spawns from. How do I specify the server karma should use to spin up a web server?

**karma.conf.js**

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Wed Apr 01 2015 16:55:42 GMT-0700 (PDT)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'requirejs'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'test-main.js',
      'specs/server.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Comment: Does Karma do that? Is it Karma's job to spin up the webserver? (Serious question.)

Comment: I don't think you need to use karma for this: karma is more for front-end testing. You can either use mocha and some other frameworks such [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) or similar.